# How would you push a list of strings to cells of a table equally?

Tags: c#, algorithm, datatable

Let's say I have a calendar, x rows and y cols

**x** represents a service for example and **y** represents the days of the week

I have a list of strings of variable count that I need to spread into this table in an equal manner.

Meaning the easiest scenario would be a list of 7 x 3 = 21 strings.

In what cells the strings are pushed does not matter.

But the results for this case would be 1 string per cell. If the list was 42 it would be 2 per cell, and so on.

But the list count will be variable so I need to know how to handle having an uneven number of strings in the table. What data structure I should use? How can I develop this algorithm?

Comment: Create a random list of 21 items.  Fill the 21 items.  Then repeat creating list of 21 items.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Nested `List` Below is the example of Nested List, Find details  [Nested List in C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nested-list)
Nested `List`. A `List` can have List elements. This is a sort of jagged list: it is similar in syntax and usage to a [jagged array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/jagged-array). In this way we can develop multidimensional Lists. This yields an easily-developed and expandable data structure.